# email validation one condition & more than one else statement in PHP

Tags: php, validation, if-statement, nested-loops

I will try to put email validation with have more than one case.
First(if):email is required.
Second(if): invalid format of email.
Third(else): Email is exist(Active User)
Fourth(else): Email is in approve(Admin is not approved account yet so its 
      still in request table)
Fifth(else):Everything goes well,post the data into database.

I try to solve this by if-else statement but in last two case I do not have any condition its just have to pass that validation.I also try switch statement, but it's not go after the first case:

Here is my validation:

```
   if(empty($_POST['email']))
     {
         $email=$_POST['email'];
         $emailError="Email is required";
         $error=true;
     }
   else
     {
          $email=$_POST['email'];
          if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
          {
            $emailError = "Invalid email format";
            $error=true;
          }
          else
              {
                 $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
                 $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                 if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
                 {
                  $emailError = "Email already exists";
                  $error=true;
                 }
               }

         else 
           {
             $sl="SELECT * FROM request WHERE email='$email'";
             $ress=mysqli_query($db,$sl);
             if (mysqli_num_rows($ress) > 0)
             {
              $emailError = "Your Accout is in process";
              $error=true;
             }
           }
      }
```

Comment: Use else if { } Condition.

Comment: your braces are not well placed

Comment: @NimeShPatel but in elseif(condition), I have to put condition right? I don't have any condition for last two cases

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi Sorry, I will take care about it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I put the condition for $error & now its working fine. remember that you have to put $exist=""; in starting.
here is my code:

```
   if(empty($_POST['email']))
   {
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $emailError="Email is required";
    $error=true;
   }
   else {
          $email=$_POST['email'];
          if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
         {
           $emailError = "Invalid email format";
           $error=true;
         }
         else
             {
                $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
                $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
                {
                 $emailError = "Email already exists";
                 $error=true;
                 $exist=1;
                }
            }
            if($exist!=1)
            {
              $sl="SELECT * FROM request WHERE email='$email'";
              $ress=mysqli_query($db,$sl);
              if (mysqli_num_rows($ress) > 0)
              {
               $emailError = "Your Accout is in process";
               $error=true;
              }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way to do this:

Declare some random variables for each error
By using the multiple if conditions make a first check if it is empty or not. Made a second check if it's match the correct format, third if value exist in db or not

I'm displaying the sample code for this

```
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
$emptyMail = 'Please provide the Email';
}else{
$notEmpty= 1;
}

if(!){     //check the preg match
wrongFromat = 'Please enter the Mail in correct format';
}else{
$correctFormat = 1;
}

if($notEmpty= 1 && $correctFormat = 1){       //check the database
//if it exist in db 
$exist = 0;
}elseif($notEmpty= 0 || $correctFormat = 0 || $notEmpty= 1 || $correctFormat = 1){
$exist = 0;
}else{
$exist = 1;
}

if($notEmpty= 1 && $correctFormat = 1 $exist = 1){  
//insert in database and send the status pending to the user
}
```

Comment: I try this but its directly goto the invalid format portion, even its empty & not moving forward for check in the database. I think i mistake somewhere, anyways any other way for solve this? thanks for help

Comment: Can you tell me on which invalid portion it is moving?

Comment: its directly stop at invalid email portion, event the tab is empty, btw I answer the question, checkout if it has any problem

Answer (score 0):

In line 1 you check  `if(empty($_POST['email']))`,
 so if it is empty you should return error, instead you try to save empty value in line 3 and so on.